# how to form submit using javascript

Tags: javascript

While I click in generate invoice I want to save value 0 and while I click cancel I want to save 1 in database using javascript.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="generate_invoice" value="yes" onClick="generate();" ><?php echo lang('generate_invoice'); ?></button>
</div>
```

In Popup

```
<div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">
                <?php echo lang('Invoice_conform'); ?>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger bulk_no del_success">
                <?php echo lang('cancel'); ?>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary bulk_yes">
                <?php echo lang('continue'); ?>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. Now please tell us what problem you're having.

Comment: There's no form in the code, you've to create a one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: what should be the javascript code to save value1 while click in continue and 0 while cancel in database

Comment: To do what? Your question is not clear at all. There is no form in there (as already noted by Teemu), you don't hint at how your backend works, we don't know how your database is working. Ignoring the fact that SO is not a code writing service, how do you expect us to help you here?